# Why is my application causing so many re-renders when using props to pass data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an CRUD like application. I have a top level parent that pulls data from API, followed by passing said down to many children, and there offspring's.

I seem to be getting a handful of extra re-renders. I would like to understand what I'm not building correctly, before I move onto a library like redux to help me with issues.

Here is my top level parent that fetches data:

```
export const GetUserStocks  = React.memo(() =>
{
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const BucketLoading = LoadingComponent(Bucket);
    const [reloadKey, setReloadKey] = useState(0);

    const [bucketState, setBucketState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        bucket: [],
    });
    const [finDataState, setFinDataState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        finData: [],
    });
    const [graphDataState, setGraphDataState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        historicalPrice: [],
    });

    const [stockCount, setStockCount] = useState('');


    const fetchBucketData = useCallback(async () =>
    {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get('bucket/' + slug + '/')
        const result = response.data;
        console.log(result)
        setBucketState({ loading: false, bucket: result });
    }, [slug]);


    const fetchFinData = useCallback(async () =>
    {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get('bucket/fin-data/' + slug)
        const result = response.data;
        setFinDataState({ loading: false, finData: result });
        setStockCount(result[0].length)
    }, [slug]);
    
    const fetchGraphData = useCallback(async () =>
    {
        const response = await axiosInstance.get('bucket/graph-price/' + slug)
        const result = response.data;
        setGraphDataState({ loading: false, historicalPrice: result });
    }, [slug]);


    useEffect(() =>
    {
        fetchBucketData();
        fetchFinData();
        fetchGraphData();
    }, [reloadKey]);

    return (
            <>
            <BucketLoading
                isLoading={bucketState.loading}
                bucket={bucketState.bucket}
                finData={finDataState.finData}
                isLoadinghistoricalPrice={graphDataState.loading}
                historicalPrice={graphDataState.historicalPrice}
                stockCount={stockCount}
                reloadKey={reloadKey => setReloadKey(reloadKey)}
                stocklist={bucketState.bucket.stock_list}
            />
            </>
    );
});
```

Here is the next child, where it passes props data onto future offspring components:

```
export const Bucket = React.memo((props) => {

    const { bucket, finData, historicalPrice, isLoadinghistoricalPrice, stockCount, reloadKey ,stocklist} = props;
    const MiniGraphsLoading = LoadingComponent(MiniGraphDisplay);
    const classes = useStyles();
    console.log(bucket)

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}></div>
            <div className={classes.heroContent}>
                <Container maxWidth="md">
                    <Typography
                        component="h1"
                        variant="h2"
                        align="center"
                        color="textPrimary"
                        gutterBottom
                        className = {classes.bucketTitle}
                    >
                        {bucket.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                        variant="body1"
                        align="center"
                        color="textSecondary"
                        // paragraph
                        className = {classes.bucketAbout}
                    >
                        {bucket.about}
                    </Typography>
                    <InputDisplay reloadKey={reloadKey} stocklist={stocklist}/>
                </Container>
                <Typography>{stockCount}</Typography>
                <Divider style={{marginBottom: "1rem"}}/>
            </div>
            <MiniGraphsLoading
                isLoading={isLoadinghistoricalPrice}
                finData={finData}
                historicalPrice={historicalPrice}
                stockCount={stockCount}
            />
            <Tables data={finData} />
            {/* <Divider style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }} /> */}
        </Container>
    );
})
```

I use `reloadKey` as a trigger (which originates from my child and sent up to the parent) to send back to my parent component as a dependency for my `useEffect` to start pulling new data from the API.

From this information above, can someone else catch the reason why I'm getting so many re-renders, I have used `memo` as a wrapper for child comps, but that didn't have much affect.

Comment: Probably your props change each time when you fetch new data.

Comment: I'm getting 3 extra renders, is each render caused by the total level from parent to child prop transfer?

Comment: What I can see you have 3 asynchronous callback and each of them change at least one state.. so it's possible that react re-render after each state change.

Comment: Okay that makes, about to test and combine it to one async call instead. Do you think that will solve this issue?

Comment: I think that can help but even if help you still have few states which can updated in different times.. remember that state updenting is asynchronous. Another think to try is yo use one reducer instead of 5 states and update it when all data are fetched.

Comment: In that case should I just use redux?

Comment: If you want you can. But you can also use useReducer hook which is built-in in react